# scale option for graphs cause troubles

Tags: graphics, books

I want to insert some pictures in my thesis (using book class). Everything seems OK until I resize my picture using **scale=0.8** option. Suddenly four errors occur as follows.

1. Line 33: ! Paragraph ended before \Gin@iii was complete.
2. Line 34: ! LaTeX Error: \begin{figure} on input line 29 ended by \end{remark}.
3. Line 34: ! Missing } inserted.
4. Line 36: ! LaTeX Error: \begin{remark} on input line 25 ended by \end{document}.

Here is my code. Why did this happen, please? Is there an easy fix, please? I can resize my pictures before inserting them, but it is not so convenient, is it? Thank you!

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside, openright]{book}

  \usepackage{amssymb}
  \usepackage{latexsym}
  \usepackage{amsfonts}
  \usepackage{amsthm}
  \usepackage{amsmath}

  \newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[chapter]

  \theoremstyle{definition}
  \newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}

  \usepackage{graphics}

\begin{document}

  % set page numbers to roman and suppress chapter numbers
  \frontmatter

  \mainmatter

\chapter{Introduction and Motivation}

\begin{remark}

Here is a picture.

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{head}
\end{figure}

\end{remark}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You have to load `graphicx` package, not `graphics`. Note the `x` at the end.

Comment: @HarishKumar Thank you! BTW, what is the major difference between the two, please?

Comment: Beside using the right package, consider resize with respect to the text layout and not use dimensions relatives to the real image size. That is, use `width=\linewidth`, `width=.6\linewidth`  or `height=.2\textheight` instead of `scale=.8`.

Comment: @HarishKumar actually `graphicx` is older (probably, by a day or so:-) but anyway the rest of your comment is correct

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Really? I wasn't aware. Thanks for the information. :-)